# Factorial system

Tags: number-theory

Factorial system,

hi how can I convert decimal number to "factorial system" like this:

$(100)_{10}$ $= 4⋅4! + 0⋅3! + 2⋅2! + 0⋅1! $ = $(4020)_{!}$

Multipliers of consecutive positions are defined by the force of consecutive positive natural numbers.

Comment: I think it's n <=

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following procedure : Find the largest factorial smaller or equal to the given number and detect the largest multiple not exceeding the given number. Subtract this multiple from the given number and continue. Factorials not appearing in this procudure correspond with the digit $0$.

Comment: Every digit belonging to $n!$ will be in the range $[0,n]$

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered here, with a nice slick solution:
[Calculating a Factorial Base Representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868774/calculating-a-factorial-base-representation)

I can explain it again here if you would like, but I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: That is correct and you can click on close below the original question to mark it as a duplicate.  You will be asked for a link to the question you believe to be the duplicate.  It will take agreement from some others before the question is closed as a duplicate.