# Is there a name for an expression that is solely the sum of integer multiples of factorials?

Tags: terminology, factorial

All natural numbers may be expressed as the sum of terms where each term is an integer coefficient multiplied by a factorial.  In each term, the coefficient is always less than or equal to the factorialised number in that term.  For example:

$$3 = 2! + 1!$$

$$11 = 3! + 2(2!) +1!$$

$$5000 = 6(6!) + 5(5!) + 3(4!) + 3! + 2!$$

Do such expressions have a name?  I have tried searching google, but was unable to come up with anything likely.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868774/calculating-a-factorial-base-representation (not a duplicate, I think, because that question was concerned with the properties of the representation rather than with terminology).

Answer (score 3):

They're apparently called [factoradic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) numerals!  But I've only ever heard it called base-factorial.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this is called the Cantor expansion.  Most elementary number theory books have some exercises about it.